# How do I find out where my Express app the response is being sent/finished?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent` in my app. I know a response is being sent before the response I intend to deliver, but I'm not sure where that's coming from. Can I log to the console when a respnose has been sent? I'm currently using [morgan](https://www.npmjs.org/package/morgan) for logging, but it only seems to log requests. I can't find a way to log every response as well.

If not, what is another effective way to hunt this problem down?

**Update:** This app runs on Azure and uses the Azure SDK for node or else I would try running it through the node debugger or node-inspector. I don't think there's a way to do this while also running the app in the emulator. I could be wrong about that.

Comment: if you want to look into your application try node-inspector. But your problem seems to be a simple bug. Somewhere in your server code was a response send already.

Comment: There should be a stack trace along with the error. If `morgan` is preventing that from being accessed/shown, then try temporarily removing `morgan` to see the stack trace.

Comment: @silom I should have mentioned this is an Azure project, so I'll have to run it through the Azure emulator. I can't see a way to run any debuggers while running the app through that emulator.

Comment: @mscdex I have the stack trace, but I believe the error happens on the response I *want* to occur. The one I need to find is the one before that which makes the second one throw the error.

Comment: @silom It seems I can still run the app through node-inspector on the Azure emulator. I'll give this a try. Thank you! http://weblogs.asp.net/jimwang/debugging-node-node-inspector-in-the-azure-emulator

Comment: @silom If you'll post your suggestion as an answer, I will mark it correct. This is going to work out nicely. Stepping through the code right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says that there was a response send already, check your code with the node-inspector  or any other debugging tool and search for the spot.

Here the [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector).

And since you work with Azure [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jimwang/debugging-node-node-inspector-in-the-azure-emulator) should help you getting started with the node-inspector.